# WordPress color picker not working on clone jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I want to add a color picker on WordPress. I tried by cloning the `<div>` and append it, but clone color picker isn't opening.

Here is what I tried:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.select-color').wpColorPicker();
  $('.more-select').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('.number-container:last').clone();
    name.find('.ppom-img-uploader-area').end().appendTo('.ppom-img-uploader-area');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="number-container">
    <label>name</label>
    <input type="text" name="">
    <label>color</label>
    <input type="text" name="color-name" class="select-color">
  </div>
  <button class="more-select">more</button>
</div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wuq6g8zd/) is also a JSFiddle (as suggested in the comments below). How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make in jsfiddle?

Comment: its wordpress plugin color picker how to add this.

Comment: can add this on wordpress and see

Comment: @Apple Orange, Just now I created the JSFiddle and I edited the question to add a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

The color picker is initialized by using this after the DOM is ready: `$('.select-color').wpColorPicker();`

Any element that did not exist when the DOM was first loaded, will not be affected by any JS that was run at the beginning. After cloning it, you need to initialize the new one.

```
$('.more-select').click (function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

    var name = $('.number-container:last').clone () ;
     name.find('.ppom-img-uploader-area').end().appendTo('.ppom-img-uploader-area');
     $('.select-color').wpColorPicker();
});
```

I can't test this for you because the color picker does not work in your snippet (you did not provide the JS for the wpColorPicker() function). I believe it will work in WordPress tho.